# Difficulty Coding SUMIF with R1C1 Notation & Dynamic Worksheet Reference

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In creating a dynamic budget spreadsheet, I'm trying to input the following code but it keeps reporting an RTE 1004 error "Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error" for the last line (Formula R1C1).  The critical parts for this is having a dynamic worksheet reference as well as the relative cell (RC[-3]) that determines the SUMIF condition for those worksheet references.  If this isn't going to work, how can I use R1C1/relative references in a SUMIF formula with dynamic worksheet references?

Shortening the code, here's what I have:

```
Dim sht as Variant
Dim shts as variant

shts = Array("Budget 1, Budget 2, Budget 3, Budget 4")

For Each sht In shts
                        
    next_row = Sheet12.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    Sheet12.Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Left(cs.Value, 6)
    Sheet12.Cells(next_row, 4).Value = Mid(cs.Value, 10, 75)
    Sheet12.Cells(next_row, 5).Value = 0
    Sheet12.Cells(next_row, 6).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(""' & sht & '!""R8C4:R1000C4,RC[-3]&"" * "",""' & sht & '!""R8C6:R1000C10)"

Next sht
```

Comment: Excel does not us single quotes: `"=SUMIF(" & sht & "!R8C4:R1000C4,RC[-3]&"" * ""," & sht & "!R8C6:R1000C10)"`

Comment: also `R8C6:R1000C10` this will be problematic as SUMIF does not do two dimensional array sum off one dimensional criteria range.

Comment: @ScottCraner - shouldn't the sheet name be wrapped in single quotes, to handle the case of a space in the name?

Comment: @BigBen yes, sorry to amend my first comment the single quotes should be in the double: `"=SUMIF('" & sht & "'!R8C4:R1000C4,RC[-3]&"" * "",'" & sht & "'!R8C6:R1000C10)"`

Comment: @BigBen - That's why I had single quotes to accommodate the space.

Comment: Correct... but you still got your double quotes mixed up a bit.

Comment: @BigBen it is hard for me to remember that, because I do not use spaces in my worksheet names, ever.

Comment: ^^^^ Smart move ^^^^

Comment: You could just add the single quotes *inside* the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm seeing the value now in not using spaces.

Comment: `"=SUMIF('" & sht & "'!R8C4:R1000C4,RC[-3]&"" * "",'" & sht & "'!R8C6:R1000C10)"` should return the correct formula regardless of spaces or not, but it will not return the value you expect, the reason is stated in my second comment.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Thanks for that answer as well.  It looks like it's only adding values in the C6 column.  The referencing issue is resolved, now I'll investigate the array summation issue.  Thank you.